# drawing a line in polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have a point in polar coordinates `(110:2cm)`, but from here I want to draw a line straight down.

Doing `(110:1cm)` is a line towards the center along 110 degrees.  Without taking `2*sin(110)` and `2*cos(110)` to find the explicit x and y location, is there a way to say draw a line down from that location?

Comment: [Relative coordinates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5btikz-pgf%5d%20relative%20coordinates) is probably the thing you want. Or how exactly is the “line straight down” specified? Does it have a certain lengths, does it have to end at a certain *y* value?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel in this instance there wasn't a certain `y` but how would it be done if that was the case?

Comment: See my answer. If it fails (because of complicated coordinates (maybe mixed with the `calc` library)) one have to fall-back to the `perpendicular cs`.

Comment: `\filldraw (110:2) circle (1pt) -- +(-90:1) node [below]{end of the line};` with (-90:1) we use only polar coordinates

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### With PSTricks:

[image]

**Option 1:**

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \qdisk(2;110){1pt}
    \psline[origin={2;110}](0,-1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Option 2:**

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}% \psrline is defined in this package but its documentation is explained in pst-node documentation, weird?
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \qdisk(2;110){1pt}
    \psrline(2;110)(0,-1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Without PSTricks:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \fill (110:2) circle (1pt);
    \draw (110:2) -- +(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Remarks for TikZ**:

- `\draw (110:2) -- +(0,-1);` The current point is `(110:2)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` (vector addition). The current point is still at `(110:2)`.
- `\draw (110:2) -- ++(0,-1);` The current point is `(110:2)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` (vector addition). The current point is moved to `(110:2)+(0,-1)`.
- `\draw (110:2) +(0,-1) -- +(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` to point `(110:2)+(0,1)`. The current point is still at `(110:2)`.
- `\draw (110:2) ++(0,-1) -- +(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)+(0,-1)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)+(0,1)`. The current point is still at `(110:2)+(0,-1)`.
- `\draw (110:2) ++(0,-1) -- ++(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)+(0,-1)`. It draws a line from point `(110:2)+(0,-1)` to point `(110:2)+(0,-1)+(0,1)`. The current point is moved to `(110:2)+(0,-1)+(0,1)` (which is equal to `(110:2)`).
- `\draw (110:2) ++(0,-1) (1,1) -- +(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)+(0,-1)`. Without drawing anything, the current point is moved to `(1,1)`. Next, it draws a line from the current point `(1,1)` to `(1,1)+(0,1)`. The current point is still at `(1,1)`.
- `\draw (110:2) ++(0,-1) (1,1) -- ++(0,1);` The current point is `(110:2)+(0,-1)`. Without drawing anything, the current point is moved to `(1,1)`. Next, it draws a line from the current point `(1,1)` to `(1,1)+(0,1)`. The current point is moved to `(1,1)+(0,1)`.

Comment: `\filldraw (110:2) circle (1pt) -- +(0,-1);`

Comment: @AlainMatthes: The circle was added to the answer just for showing the point `(110:2)`. It should be regarded as an auxiliary object so it was intentionally separated from the line construction syntax for the sake of clearness.

Comment: Your remarks section was very useful! Good job, nice info

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked for it.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % for the grid
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={gridded,nodes={above,at end, font=\tiny}}} % example settings

\tikzset{
  to y/.style={
    to path={-- (\tikztostart|-0,\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  to x/.style={
    to path={-- (\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget,0) \tikztonodes}},
  to y*/.style={
    to path={-- (\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  to x*/.style={
    to path={-- (\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw (110:2) node {(110:2)} -- ++ (down:1) node[midway,right] {I'm 1cm long.}; % this line is 1cm long
% also possible is (-90:1) or (90:-1) or (0,-1) or …
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw (110:2) node {(110:2)} -- (110:2|-0,1) node[right] {Here is $y=1$}; % this line goes from (110:2cm) down where y = 1cm
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw (110:3) node {(110:3)} to[to y] node[below] {$y=1.5$} (1.5) to[to x] node[above] {$x=0$} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

[image]

[image]